# How can I teach my pokemon moves it missed?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've been playing Pokemon Y. I just evolved my Eevee into a Glaceon at level 41.

Now I just realized that the *Hail* ability is learned by Glaceon at level 37, so it skipped that. Is there any way it can still learn the *Hail* ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Go to the [Move Reminder](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Move_Reminder#Generation_VI) in Dendemille Town, northeast of the Pokemon Center. If you give her a Heart Scale, she can teach your Pokemon moves they would have learned at lower levels. For some Pokemon, this even includes levels you can't actually get them at! For example, the Move Reminder is the only way to teach a Lopunny Rototiller, which it gets at level 1.

Note that the Move Reminder can only teach a Pokemon moves on its level-up learnlist or moves it knew when it was generated. That means that, for example, egg moves and event moves are okay, but you can't remind a Pokemon of moves it learned by TM or moves only its pre-evolutions would learn by level-up.

Comment: Four seconds. That was close!

Comment: @FEichinger: Indeed it was.