# Can Pokémon learn moves between generations?

Tags: pokemon-series

If you transfer a Pokémon from an earlier generation to a later one, can it learn the moves of that generation or is it restricted to the earlier ones?  And can Pokémon that had generation exclusive moves learn them again (in later gens) from the Move Tutor / Reminder?

I know that from RBY to Sun or Moon they will get their hidden ability, but I'm specifically after movesets.

There is a similar(ish) questions here but it doesn't quite cover it.

[Which of the original 151 Pokemon learn moves AS they are evolving?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27895/which-of-the-original-151-pokemon-learn-moves-as-they-are-evolving)

[How can I teach my pokemon moves it missed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159294/how-can-i-teach-my-pokemon-moves-it-missed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the posts in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74796098), a Pokémon will have the moveset of whatever game it is in. It won't forget what it's already learned, even if it has moves that it can't learn in Sun/Moon, but it won't be able to re-learn them if they forget the moves at some point.

> The learnset of a Pokemon always depends on the game it's in. So, if you have a Pikachu in, say, Yellow it will only ever learn moves it can learn in yellow but when you transfer it to Sun/Moon it will only be able to (re)learn moves it can learn in Sun/Moon. It will keep the moves it had in Yellow if you transfer it but I have no idea if you can relearn the "Yellow Version-only" moves if your Pikachu forgets them.
>
> Egg moves and other non-learnset moves were only recognized from Gen 6 and up, so anything not on the learnset will not be relearnable.

Comment: To clarify, the move relearner doesn't actually relearn forgotten moves, it allows learning any move in the extended moveset, which includes any moves the Pokémon can learn by level-up/has as level 1 moves in that generation, or received as Egg moves. As far as I know, there have never been event-exclusive moves that were not also inherited as Egg moves, but I might be wrong there. If there are, they cannot be relearned after forgetting them.

Comment: @scenia There have been LOTS of event-exclusive moves. Even moves that only come from events such as Celebrate, Hold Hands, and Happy Hour.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer yes, I know. But are they all non-inheritable? I'm not sure, but I think there were at least some that were passed on.

Comment: @scenia By definition, event-exclusive moves can't be learned any other way. In fact, the opposite, where a Pokémon's Egg move can only be learned through an event, is much more rare. I can only think of Dratini's Extreme Speed as an example.